# How to get the most significant non-zero byte in a 32 bit integer without a while loop?

Tags: bit-manipulation

I have a method to extract the most significant, non-zero byte in an integer using the following method:

```
private static int getFirstByte(int n)
{
    while (n > 0xFF)
        n >>= 8;

    return n;
}
```

There's a logic problem with this method. The integer parameter could be negative, which means it would return the number being passed in, which is incorrect.

There is also a possible issue with the method itself. It is using a while loop.

Is there a way to perform this logic without a while loop and also possibly avoiding the incorrectly returned result for negative numbers?

Comment: Why is the while loop a problem? Anyway, there's only four bytes in there, so you can write down four explicit steps.

Comment: If I can perform the same operation without a for loop, it will be less runtime instructions. It's not a bottleneck, but it would be nice to know, nonetheless.

Comment: Your toolchain may provide a "count leading zeros" intrinsic that maps directly to a fast hardware instruction, e.g. __builtin_clz() in gcc. Once you have numzeros = clz(n), you could extract the byte with code like (((unsigned int)n) >> ((sizeof(int)-(numzeros/8))*8)) & 0xff, for non-zero n. Note that right shift of a negative quantity invokes undefined behavior in C, thus the cast to unsigned int. Similarly, shift amounts equal to operand size lead to undefined behavior, which is why n must not be zero.

Comment: The expression I gave above was incorrect. The following is the corrected version, and handles an input of zero as well: int getFirstByte (int n) { int lz = __builtin_clz(n); return n ? ((unsigned int)n >> ((sizeof(n)-(lz/8)-1)*8)) : n; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume by get the first non-zero `byte` in an `int` you mean natural 8 bit breaks of the `int` and not a dynamic 8 bit break.

Natural 8 bit breaks:

`00000000`**`|`**`00010110`**`|`**`10110010`**`|`**`11110001` ==> `00010110`

Dynamic 8 bit break:

`00000000000`**`|`**`10110101`**`|`**`1001011110001` ==> `10110101`

This will return the first non-zero `byte` on a natural 8-bit break of an `int` without looping or branching. This code may or may not be more efficient then `paulsm4`'s answer. Be sure to do benchmarking and/or profiling of the code to determine which is best for you.

**Java Code:** [`ideone link`](http://ideone.com/mR84SU)

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i,j;
        for (i=0,j=1; i<32; ++i,j<<=1) {
          System.out.printf("0x%08x : 0x%02x\n",j,getByte(j));
        }
    }
    public static byte getByte(int n) {
        int x = n; 
        x |=   (x >>>  1);
        x |=   (x >>>  2);
        x |=   (x >>>  4);
        x |=   (x >>>  8);
        x |=   (x >>> 16);
        x -=  ((x >>>  1) & 0x55555555);
        x  = (((x >>>  2) & 0x33333333) + (x & 0x33333333));
        x  = (((x >>>  4) + x) & 0x0f0f0f0f);
        x +=   (x >>>  8);
        x +=   (x >>> 16);
        x &= 0x0000003f;
        x  = 32 - x;     // x now equals the number of leading zeros
        x &= 0x00000038; // mask out last 3 bits (cause natural byte break)
        return (byte)((n&(0xFF000000>>>x))>>>(24-x));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm impressed! Bit arithmetic taken to the next level. :)

Comment: @Brad The above code *might* be able to be reduced to fewer operations but I didn't feel like exploring that possibility.

Answer (score 3):

Not  clever, not elegant - but I believe it does "extract the most significant, non-zero byte in an integer ... without using a loop":

```
private static int getFirstByte(int n) {
  int i;
  if ((i = n & 0xff000000) != 0)
     return (i >> 24) & 0xff;
  if ((i = n & 0xff0000) != 0)
    return (i >> 16) & 0xff;
  if ((i = n & 0xff00) != 0)
    return (i >> 8) & 0xff;
  // all of the higher bytes are zeroes
  return n;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `log n / log 256`… But then you’d have a bigger problem.